# Server Error Error: Configuration must contain projectId‘

Tags: next.js, sanity

I followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/mx1dbMzd3tU

When i try to connect sanity and next i get this error

Server Error
Error: Configuration must contain projectId‘

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! - In order for anyone to help you, post parts of the code that apply to this error - A MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is recommended so others can replicate and provide you direction - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes up when you're missing the projectId. You have to use projectId when creating your Sanity client instance:

```
const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: 'yourproject-id',
  dataset: 'your dataset',
  token: 'Sanity build token',
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  useCdn: false // `false` if you want to ensure fresh data
})
```

Answer (score 4):

here are the step to follow:

1. Create **.env.local** file
2. add in your variables starting by **NEXT_PUBLIC_**

Example for the variable name **PROJECT_ID** it turn into **NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID**

This allow environment variable to be exposed to the browser